# Use imported package within the __del__ method

Tags: python, python-import, del

I am experimenting with Telegram bots. I have created a simple class to send messages and I want it to send me a warning message when the `TelegramBot` object is deleted. My code is:

```
import requests
class TelegramBot:
    def __init__(self, token, id):
        self.token = token
        self.id = id

    def send_msg(self, msg: str):
        send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + self.token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + self.id + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + msg
        response = requests.get(send_text)
        return response.json()

    def __del__(self):
        self.send_msg('WARNING: TelegramBot object is being deleted')
```

and it works fine. The problem is within the `__del__` method. Instead of sending the warning msg I am getting an error:

```
Exception ignored in: <function TelegramBot.__del__ at 0x7f1927c74280>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check_flight_status.py", line 20, in __del__
  File "check_flight_status.py", line 16, in send_msg
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 996, in _validate_conn
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 319, in connect
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
```

and I believe it has to do with the fact that the `requests` package is being "destroyed" before the `TelegramBot` object.

So, how can I send a message when the object is deleted?

Comment: Why do you need a warning? Seems like you're solving the wrong problem. However, you could create a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager).

Comment: What is the actual question here? `__del__` is not a safe place to do that, for the reasons you've already surmised.

Comment: I forgot the question. How can I send a warning message when this object is deleted?

Comment: You're quite right: it probably was. In fact, there is no guarantee that `TelegramBot.__del__` itself will be called; an implementation is not required to perform garbage collection when *all* memory is about to be returned to the operating system.

Comment: You might want to check the `atexit` module: you probably care more that your script is exiting than that a particular instance of `TelegramBot` is being garbage-collected while the script will continue to run.

Comment: @chepner you are right, I have a simple script that uses an instance of ```TelegramBot``` within a ```while True:``` loop. I want to receive a warning if by some reason this script stops running. I thought that the most simple way to do this is as I posted in my question, however I learned it i not. I will check the ```atexit``` module.

Answer (score -1):

You have more way to solve your issue. The problem is in the caller side. Probably you don't delete the object of `TelegramBot` after usage.

I have written a representative example for you.

**Code (Wrong):**

```
import requests

class Test(object):

    def printer(self):
        print("FOO")

    def _close_con(self):
        import encodings.idna  # Sometimes it's needed for "LookupError: unknown encoding: idna" issue.
        response = requests.get('https://google.com')
        print("Status Code: {}".format(response.status_code))

    def __del__(self):
        self._close_con()

t = Test()
t.printer()
print("End of script")
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
FOO
End of script
Exception ignored in: <bound method Test.__del__ of <__main__.Test object at 0x7f7b14e5ca58>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in __del__
  File "test.py", line 10, in _close_con
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
```

If I delete the object (`t`) of `Test` class then the Exception is fixed.

**Fixed part:**

```
t = Test()
t.printer()
print("End of script")
del t
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
FOO
End of script
Status Code: 200
```

Or another solution to not creating instance from the class, only call it directly. In this case the GC will do everything for you.

**Fixed part:**

```
Test().printer()
print("End of script")
```

Output:

```
>>> python3 test.py 
FOO
Status Code: 200
End of script
```

As you can see above the object reference has been destroyed (by GC) after the usage (This is the reason why the sequence of messages is different than the other example).